# Perl Net::Google::Spreadsheets, how to get worksheet title?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

I am trying to get titles of my worksheets via Perl Net::Google::Spreadsheets
and cant figured out how to do it.

I know that: my @wsts = $spreadsheet->worksheets;
returns array of worksheets objects. I have dumped all of them and there is no the title in them.

I need your advice.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation from Perl Net::Google:Spreadsheets says:

```
my @wsts = $spreadsheet->worksheets;
for (@wsts){
    print $_->title;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I would be appreciate if you point me to the documentation where you found description about title method. I have checked CPAN and there is no any sign of it there.
Also do you know a way to rename worksheet, because it is impossible to delete last one from spreadsheet?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please would you indicate where in the documentation you found this information? It is not in the documentation for [Net::Google::Spreadsheets](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Spreadsheets)

Comment: You can use $_->delete as delete function. Documentation is the author document and all other sources like tests in my eyes. Then you can see it in the file 03_worksheet.t